# How to return an object from a function that contains a Promise and a .then and how to get the returned value in another function?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, promise, return, es6-promise

how can i return an object from a function that contains a **Promise** and a **.then**; and how can i get the returned value from that function, in another function? Here is the function that contains the Promise and the object that i want to return is **obj**:

```
function searchdb(user, key){
    var ok;
    const list = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        MongoClient.connect(uri, function(err, db) {
            var dbc = db.db("chat");
            dbc.collection("chat_messages").find({$or: [ {user1: key, user2: user}, {user1: user, user2: key} ]}).toArray(function (err, result){
                if(err) {
                    reject(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(result);         
                }
                if(result[0].user1 == key){
                    ok = 1;
                }
                else{
                    ok = 2;
                }
            });
        db.close();
            
        });
        
    });
    var obj = {};

        list.then(result => {  
        if (ok == 1){
            obj[result[0].user1] = result[0].user2_seen;
        }else{
            obj[result[0].user2] =result[0].user1_seen;
        }
        console.log(obj);              <--------------- here its working
        }).catch(err => console.log(err.message));

        return obj; 
}
```

And here is the function where i want to get the return:

```
function get(data){
    suser = data[0]
    obj = data[1];
    
    for (var i in obj){
        var key = Object.keys(obj[i])[0];

        var a = searchdb(suser, key);
        console.log(a);       <-------------- here its not working
    }
}
```

I just can't return and get the return from that function, everything else its working fine. Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your main function at the top level `return new promise` and resolve it whenever obj promise is solved and store it in `newVarible`.
Then Use `promise.all("newVarible")` after that you'll be able to get values of obj after the promise is being resolved anywhere.